# How to convert a class implementing java.lang.Comparable to implement Scala.Ordered?

Tags: java, scala, programming-languages, interop, comparison

Is renaming `extends Comparable[A]` to `extends Ordered[A]` and renaming `def compareTo` to `def compare` enough or is there anything I should take care of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're correct, that's all you need to do. The other methods in `Ordered` will use their default implementations, which go as follows:

```
def <  (that: A): Boolean = (this compare that) <  0
def >  (that: A): Boolean = (this compare that) >  0
def <= (that: A): Boolean = (this compare that) <= 0
def >= (that: A): Boolean = (this compare that) >= 0
def compareTo(that: A): Int = compare(that)
```

The only thing that doesn't have a default implementation in `Ordered` is compare, which you'll be defining using your old `compareTo` method. Should work, provided the above is what you want for your other comparisons.